# How to import font in Android studio

Tags: android, utf-8, fonts, assets

I am trying to change the font style in my Android App. So I copy and paste the font file (.ttf) into the assets folder. After pasting it show's **File was loaded in the wrong encoding :UTF-8**. How can I solve it? (attached picture below)

**Note :**
I already tried following ways.

a) convert file encoding to UTF-8

b) set the right file encoding in your build.gradle script.

But the problem is not solved yet. It still shows encode formats error.

[image]

Comment: What exactly you want to do ?

Comment: I think you want to load a custom font and apply that font to some text in the app..

Comment: I had faced this issue once. It was because the .tff file was linked to txt file type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced similar issue when I was playing with fonts. I think you are facing the same issue. In my Android Studio .tff file was linked to a text file. I changed that in the File Type option in Settings and font was working fine.

Steps:

1. Go to Settings
2. Select File Type
3. Search for .tff file
4. Deactivate linking as text (it maybe some other type in your case)

Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou @Sreeram TP. This post may help to resolve that problem completely. I show my solution below.

After deactivating linking as text (pic1 below)
[image: deactivate linking as text]

I deleted and re-pasted my `font.ttf` file. It then shows the following alert (pic2 below):

[image: alert: Register New File Type Association]

I selected **Open matching file in associated application**.

This solved my problem completely.

Comment: Welcome. It took hours for me to resolve this issue when I had it. May this post help others.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem actually. You can still use the custom font like this :

`TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "yourfont.ttf");
 text.setTypeface(font);`